# Proving convergence or divergence of series: tips and recommendations

Tags: undergraduate-education, calculus, examples, mathematical-analysis, big-list

This is a follow up of my [question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865440/proving-convergence-or-divergence-of-series-tips-and-tricks). Which tips and recommendations would you give students who want to investigate series about convergence or divergence?

So far we have collected:

- It is good to [start with the term test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1865452/32951).
- For Series of the form $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ [the root test is often useful](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1865463/32951).
- [$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^p}$ converges for $p>1$ and diverges for $p\le1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1867233/32951).
- [Krummer's test is also useful](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1865566/32951).

Which recommondations would you add to the above list?

Comment: Maybe emphasize more the importance of pattern-recognition. You mentioned p-series, but a student should also be able to quickly recognize geometric and alternating series (of the type easily shown to be convergent). Furthermore, students should be able to recognize when something is *asymptotically* equivalent to one of these known series (this is often formalized by the limit comparison test). For example, they should be able to look at a sum with terms of the form `1/(2n+1)` and be able to instantly recognize it as being essentially the same thing as a harmonic series.

Comment: Beyond these excellent suggestions already made, it's also important to have some sense of relative growth. For example, polynomials always lose to exponentials, but exponentials can't survive a factorial...

Answer (score 1):

The heuristics I emphasize in my AP Calculus class are as follows:

(1) Check the nth term test before you do anything else. (As noted in your list)

(2) Check to make sure you don't have a straightforward p-series, alternating series, or geometric series before proceeding with the other alternatives.

(3) A limit comparison test to an appropriate p-series almost always works for quotients involving polynomials and similar expressions (by similar, I mean expressions which have fractional powers instead of just non-negative integers, etc.).

(4) The ratio test almost always works for series involving exponential expressions and factorials. (Yes, the root test is also excellent for exponentials, but I tend to emphasize the ratio test since it's more versatile. I would not advise having students jump to the root test in most other situations.)

There are a handful of oddballs for which these heuristics don't work, but these cover a vast majority of the commonly encountered problems.